# Multiple functions using the same template?

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to include more than one function in the same template instead of rewriting the template twice? Like if you were writing:

```
template <typename T>
void A() {
    //...
}

template <typename T>
void B() {
    //...
}
```

Those are not the same function, but they share a similar template (using the generic type `T`). Is there a way to initialize the template only once?

Comment: @Karoly Horvath wat

Comment: There is no way to do it in C++ except using `template class`, but it's not much clear way to achieve what you want to.

Comment: Do you really mean *"rewriting the template <typename T> line twice"* when you say *"rewriting the template twice"*?

Comment: @user6245072 D is a programming language, coming from C++, see wikipedia on the D language

Comment: @LibertyPaul: The use-case that sent me looking for this question was wanting to share a template-dependent typedef between two functions, like writing `typedef typename std::conditional< lots, of, typing> array_or_unordered_map` once and using the defined type in two free functions.  Instead of repeating the 4-line std::conditional inside each function.  The version in the question here seems too simplistic and wouldn't seem to gain anything / doesn't have anything to share based on the templates.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Grouping them inside a class template would achieve that.

```
template <class T>
struct Functions {
    static void A() { /*...*/ }
    static void B() { /*...*/ }
};
```

However, you lose the ability to deduce `T` from the functions' arguments, and the calling syntax is longer :

```
Functions<double>::A();
```

Comment: They should be made static.

Comment: @Borgleader they should indeed ! Fortunately, my coffee is on the way.