# refactor MANY functions to receive any type of parameter elegantly (template<any>)

Tags: c++, function, templates

I have a custom datastructure.

```
template<class T> class MyArray3D{
    public: void setElement(const int* index,const T& t){
        //do something about "index[0,1,2]"
    }
    public: T& get(const int* index){
        //do something about "index[0,1,2]"
    }
    public: void reserve(const int* index1,const int* index2){
        //do something about "index1,2[0,1,2]" (e.g. index can be negative)
    }
    //about 20 functions, and some fields
};
```

Everything is good.        It is currently used by many classes.
Then I want those functions to accept anything (`index`) that has `operator[]`.

### My poor solution

Here is a correct (but not good) way to do.
I change `const int*` to `template INT_ARRAY`:-

```
template<class T> class MyArray3D{
    public: template<class IARRAY> void setElement(IARRAY index,const T& t){
        //do something about "index[0,1,2]"
    }
    public: template<class IARRAY> T& get(IARRAY index){
        //do something about "index[0,1,2]"
    }
    public: template<class IARRAY1,class IARRAY2> 
      void reserve(IARRAY1 index1,IARRAY2 index2){
        //do something about "index1,2[0,1,2]" (e.g. index can be negative)
    }
    //about 20 functions, and some fields
};
```

The above refactoring is tedious.     I have to do that for all functions.

If a function has 4 `const int*`, it will be prefixed as `template<class IARRAY1,class IARRAY2,class IARRAY3,class IARRAY4>` - so ugly.

### Question

How to refactor above function elegantly (less repetitive & shorter code)?

I am dreaming about something like :-

```
template<class T> class MyArray3D{
    using IARRAY1 = please don't care about my type; ????
    public: void setElement(IARRAY1 index,const T& t);
    public: T& get(IARRAY1 index);
    public: void reserve(IARRAY1 index1,IARRAY1 index2);
};
```

**Here are the related questions :-**

- [Multiple functions using the same template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642158/multiple-functions-using-the-same-template)   : but the functions has no parameter
- [is it possible to make function that will accept multiple data types for given argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627625/is-it-possible-to-make-function-that-will-accept-multiple-data-types-for-given-a) : the template solution is same as my poor approach, and I don't think union is suitable for my case

Comment: If you want *template function argument deduction* and to accept any type this is the proper way of doing it, despite it being non-concise.

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo  Thank a lot.  It is good to know that my poor solution is a proper way.     I want the *template function argument deduction* (i.e. no need to indicate `<const int*>` manually).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, if you want *template function argument deduction* and to accept any type this is the proper way of doing it, despite it being non-concise.

Hopefully we'll get [*abbreviated Concepts Lite syntax*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Abbreviated_templates) in the future, which would allow you to do something like:

```
concept bool Indexable = /* ... */;

template<class T> class MyArray3D{
public: 
    void setElement(Indexable index, const T& t);
    T& get(Indexable index);
    void reserve(Indexable index1, Indexable index2);
};
```

Comment: Thank, it is very useful.  I am secretly praying that you are wrong - I wish there is a better solution without *concept*.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

```
template <typename... T>
void foo(T&&... args)
{
    auto tuple = std::make_tuple(std::forward<T>(args)...);

    auto indexer1 = std::get<0>(tuple);
    auto indexer2 = std::get<1>(tuple);
    auto indexer3 = std::get<2>(tuple);
    auto indexer4 = std::get<3>(tuple);
    // etc
}
```

If your indexers access contiguous memory you could use [GSL's span](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/tree/master/include/gsl) over the type `T` returned by the indexer (or borrow the idea and write your own):

```
 template <typename T>
 void foo(span<T> indexer1, span<T> indexer2, span<T> indexer3, span<T> indexer4)
 {
 }
```